# How do I restart my code if an error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project that will web scrape the "Summary" section of a random disease on the NIH GARD website. I'd like to use this to create a kind of "Disease of the day" where the results are sent to my inbox.

Not every disease on the NIH GARD site has a summary - and that's okay. If that's the case, I'd like the code to restart, pick another disease, and carry on. If that one doesn't have a summary, again, I'd like the code to restart. I know that this is a type of loop, but I'm not sure how the error fits into this.

PS - I know I have a lot TO learn with python. My original programming language was SAS and I know my writing style mirrors that (create a new variable every time, etc).

```
import requests, random, re

Alpha = ('0-9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
RandLetter = random.choice(Alpha)
pattern = r'\[.*?\]'

main_url = 'https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov/diseases/browse-by-first-letter/' + RandLetter

result = requests.get(main_url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

#find all diseases on the page
soup1 = soup.find("ul", class_ = "listing-diseases")

#creates dictionary of disease name, disease page link
d = {i.text: i.get('href') for i in soup1('a')}

#selects a random disease
e = random.choice(list(d.items()))

#web scraping for random disease
new_url = 'https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov' + e[1]
result1 = requests.get(new_url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(result1.text, 'html.parser')

#finds the Summary of the disease
soup3 = soup2.find(id="readSpeaker_Summary").get_text()

#cleans up the string and prepares it for an email
soup3 = ''.join(soup3.split("Listen")[1::])
soup3 = str(soup3.strip())
soup3 = re.sub(pattern, '', soup3)
soup3 = soup3 + ' You can learn more from the NIH Genetic & Rare Diseases Information Center' + new_url

#email code omitted
```

Comment: Using try/except ?

Comment: Try iterating through all the diseases using a for loop, and error checking using a try-except

Comment: use try - except

Comment: Can you be more specific? There is plenty of information available on handling exceptions, have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```py
import requests, random, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Alpha = ['0-9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
random.shuffle(Alpha)
pattern = r'\[.*?\]'
_exit = False
for RandLetter in Alpha:
    if _exit: break

    main_url = 'https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov/diseases/browse-by-first-letter/' + RandLetter

    result = requests.get(main_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

    #find all diseases on the page
    soup1 = soup.find("ul", class_ = "listing-diseases")

    #creates dictionary of disease name, disease page link
    d = {i.text: i.get('href') for i in soup1('a')}

    #selects a random disease
    diseases = random.choice(list(d.items()))


    for disease in diseases:
        #web scraping for random disease
        new_url = 'https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov' + disease
        result1 = requests.get(new_url)

        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(result1.text, 'html.parser')

        #finds the Summary of the disease
        try:
            soup3 = soup2.find(id="readSpeaker_Summary").get_text()
        except:
            continue

        #cleans up the string and prepares it for an email
        soup3 = ''.join(soup3.split("Listen")[1::])
        soup3 = str(soup3.strip())
        soup3 = re.sub(pattern, '', soup3)
        soup3 = soup3 + ' You can learn more from the NIH Genetic & Rare Diseases InformationCenter' + new_url
        _exit = True
        break
```

I changed the code so it iterated through every letter in a random order, just in case all of the diseases starting with a specific letter had no info page. I then iterated through all diseases shown on the page. If iIfound one, it would exit both loops.